# scala jar step fail on EMR with exit code 10

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I'm trying to launch a simple application on EMR.

I used SBT to compile a jar using:

SBT:

```
name := "exampleTest1 Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "joda-time"         % "joda-time"           % "2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.2"
```

the scala code:

```
 /* exampleTest1.scala */
package org.apache.spark.examples
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
object exampleTest1 {
  def main() {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("exampleTest1")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val yesterday = DateTime.now().minusDays(1)
val TestString = "s3n://logs.xxxxxxx.com/yyyyyy/zzzz/"+yesterday.toString("yyyy/MM/dd/yyyy-MM-dd*")
val fullconv            = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "false").load("s"+TestString).selectExpr("C0  as datetime", "C1  as ip").registerTempTable("example")
sqlContext.sql("""select * from example limit 1000""").coalesce(10).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(s"s3n://dev.xxx.com/newSparkResults/sample"+yesterday)

  }
}
```

when I try to add a step to an existing cluster on EMR I get the following error

```
     16/02/09 10:55:11 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:12 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:13 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:14 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:15 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:18 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/02/09 10:55:19 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455007292848_0007 (state: FAILED)
16/02/09 10:55:19 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1455007292848_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1455007292848_0007_000002 exited with  exitCode: 10
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ip-10-65-65-226.ec2.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1455007292848_0007Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1455007292848_0007_02_000001
Exit code: 10
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=10: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

what does exit code 10 mean? better yet - what am I doing wrong?

any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can mean a lot of things - You should look at the container logs for an explanation:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1455007292848_0007
```

will print the logs to stdout.

Comment: Thank you !! That saved me a lot of time ;)

Comment: been struggling for 10 minutes: 
-applicationId instead of -application_id

Comment: true, just changed it.